# Realm for iOS. Lazy data loading?

Tags: ios, realm

I am trying to use Realm in my new project.
But am interested in:

I have 10k objects of MyType.
And I want to filter and display only most recent 10 of them.

Will all of them be moved to RAM to operate/filter them?
'realm.objects(MyType).filter(...)' - I'm just worried about 10k objects and their data would litter the app memory in case of query like above.

No? It's OK?

Answer (score 1):

When you filter objects, your query is constructed in a C++ DSL, which is efficiently evaluated, bringing in some optimizations to run it fast depending on the concrete property types.
Accessor objects are instantiated by the binding lazily when you retrieve each object out of your results. So in your case only for the first 10 objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And secondary: if I have the List<> of other items, and call the .description of object that holds this List, I can see all these items in log. Does it mean that their data are requested at the moment of printing the description?

Comment: Yes, the data is instantly fetched at the moment it is accessed. But you will only see the first 100 objects. If there should be more objects, you will see at the end an output informing you about how many more were skipped.

Comment: So, if my object has "name" as string and "children" as list, and I want to access just its name, children would not be fetched until I access exactly any child from that list? :)